# NSURLConnection, Login then Post Image

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

**I'm trying to upload a picture to my website from my iPhone, but I need to authenticate first.**

My first attempt was to send an HTTP Post request with my login credentials using NSMutableURLRequest, and then sending the image in a similar fashion with a second NSMutableURLRequest (in a separate NSURLConnection). But that failed since no session data was kept from the login to the image post. I still got auth errors on the second request.

I thought I would be clever and create a hidden UIWebView and just call `[webview loadRequest:request];` for both login and then post image, where request is of type `NSMutableURLRequest`. This worked great and now I'm able to upload images to my website.....

....However, when I tried on my iPod touch, I get the infamous `received memory warning` followed by an app crash when I call `[webview loadRequest:request];` I'm only allocating about 10MB of memory for the entire app (thanks to profiler) so my guess it it's not in the request itself, but how UIWebView handles it. I think the "view" part of the UIWebivew is allocating a lot of memory.

**Here's my question:** how do I persist the session and login data between NSURLConnections so that I don't have to use a UIWebView?

pseudocode:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:180];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [ request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

    NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://website.com/login.php"];

     NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[@"username=me&password=password&" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];    

    [request setURL:url];
```

Then:

```
    [self.webview loadRequest:request];
```

Or:

```
    NSURLConnection* connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (connection) {
        NSLog(@"Login Opened");
        responseData = [NSMutableData data];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Logon failed");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Authentication depends on correct functioning of cookies. It looks like you are using the web view's loadRequest for one of your requests. If you just use `NSURLConnection` for both requests, it should correctly manage reading the cookie from the first response and sending it in the second request on your behalf. (See the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/URLOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001834-157091).) If this still isn't working, then there may be a problem with your session cookie settings on your server.